# How many times is a view used

Tags: views

Recently i'been assigned to a drupal project already in development. I need to change a view but the site is quite complex. Is there a way to know how many times is a view being used?

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

### [Views Usage Audit](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_usage_audit)

From project page:

> This module can help you refactor a Drupal codebase by locating redundant views and displays or simply improving your understanding of what views are used where.
>   It achieves this by logging where views get executed. You can then run reports from drush or through the UI

[image]

Answer (score 0):

when you say "how many times" you probably mean "in how many 'places' in the site" the view is being used to display data...Right?

Well, an easy way to do this is to check how many and what kind of **displays** this view has. You can see this in the edit page of the view, it is the bar above the main view "frame", with each tab denote a different display. These displays can be of different type, such as "page", "block", "context" etc.

In case of pages, you just check the corresponding view "frame window". There you can find the node number (url) or the alias.

In case of blocks, go to the block page, find the corresponding (produced) block (it's name can be found on the **views** edit page) , go to it's edit page, and there you can see various information about the "places" (regions, zones etc) where the block is being displayed. Also you can find in which nodes, for which roles etc.